# Muscle pain after workout

Tags: workout-routines, workout, upper-body-workout, post-workout

Actually when I workout some day. Like lifted dumbles,or do sit-ups , then I feel everything is normal,I actually could do without any problem.. But the next day I always feel pain in my muscles of hand and also belly muscles...My question is that is it normal...Or am I doing something wrong....
I become unable to workout the next day due to the pain...after 2-3 days I start the workout again,but the same thing happens again.

Answer (score 1):

In 99.9% of cases it's called DOMS or delayed onset muscle soreness. When you start working out again after a gap of non activity, your muscles will get really sore. However, in my personal experience and that of many others around me, the best way to deal with DOMS is to get back in the gym and keep moving around. You have to push through the pain and still try to hit those reps albeit at lower weights. Do some light cardio and active stretching around the area you feel sore in. Just don't sit around. Drink lots of water, get your protein/carbs to repair the fibers you tore and stay consistent with your workouts.

There is an unlikely chance you worked out so hard you got rhabdo. You can look that up for the symptoms and if you feel it might match you, see a doctor, don't consult an online forum.

Comment: Thanks mobcity zkore. It seems the 1st case is right for me..thank you very much for the answer..